# Is there a way to get current location in a tunnel

Tags: android, geolocation

I am trying to get the current location, the code works most of the times. But location updates fail to work in a tunnel, despite the fact that mobile reception presents.

I have tried and traced through the following two methods:

```
  Location NetLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
  Location GPSLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Neither seems to update in the tunnel. I have cross checked with a few other apps and noticed that location service is working correctly in google map.

[Whole function is linked here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f8c81ad5bf370f1c6bb5c4996d939d2b)

So is there anyways I could get correct location updates in a tunnel?

Comment: Do you mean there is no GPS reception in a tunnel? Indeed there is no.

Comment: @greenapps I know there is no GPS reception in a tunnel, but google map gets correct location info in the tunnel, so there must be a way to get the right location. The question is, is the API available to other apps?

Comment: Google map gets correct location info? From who? Makes no sense. Please elaborate what you mean.

Comment: Triangulation of base stations is one way for example. There are ways of doing this and that's what I am trying to find out.

Comment: What does that have to do with Google maps? And why dont you just ask for triangulation of mobile stations?

Comment: The same reason why I am not writing my app in machine code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116982/discussion-between-telkitty-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 1):

Google has this new API called fusedLocationAPI, you could probably try using that. Here's the sample code -

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener  {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;

private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE = 42;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    initGoogleApiClient();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
    } else {
        getLastKnownLocation();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getLastKnownLocation();
        } else {
            startLocationActivity();
        }
    }
}

private void getLastKnownLocation() {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}

private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
}
```

This is just a higher-level overview of what could be done. The code could be further customized by adding location update intervals and so on. You could refer this site - https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html for further info.